# Passing in query parameters to a WCF Service

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, wcf-binding

I'm slight confused on how to do this. I've followed some examples after searching but still cant get this working then again most examples seem to target Json (not sure if that would make a difference).

Im using basicHttpBinding.

So i have a simple Interface:

```
<ServiceContract()>
 Public Interface ICustomersService
<OperationContract()>
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="SaveName/{name}")> 
Sub SaveName(ByVal name as string)
```

Next i create my hosting application which works and i can reach the WSDL page and can view SaveName.

The current URL is `http://example.com/`

I would like to pass in a name which then saves to the database. Im expecting the URL to be along the lines of

```
http://example.com/SaveName?name="Tony"
```

That doesnt work so i tried a couple of variations using standard query string parameters but non work.

Am i doing something wrong or is there a step missing?

Comment: You've included the C# tag, but this doesn't seem to have anything to do with C#.

Comment: The issue could relate to a C# user - this problem wouldn't be code specific to the language but could attract those that may have resolved it in the past and not necessarily browsing the WCF tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `WebGet` / `WebInvoke` attributes, you cannot use a `basicHttpBinding` (or, you can use it, but those attributes will be ignored). BasicHttpBinding is one of the bindings that use the SOAP protocol, and it has some strong requirements regarding the format of the message (in a nutshell, almost everything goes in the request body, and some addressing parameters may go in HTTP headers).

To be able to define your endpoint operations using the `WebGet` attribute, your endpoint needs to use the `webHttpBinding`, and it also needs to have the `<webHttp/>` behavior applied to it (`WebHttpBehavior`, if you're defining your endpoint via code).

One more thing worth pointing out: if you use a "web" endpoint, the WSDL will not have all the information that you need to connect a client to it, so you won't be able to use the "WCF test client" to talk to it. More information about it at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/26/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work.aspx).

Comment: Ok i will read up on that link but if i go down the route of passing in parameters using webHttpBinding could my URL still be http://example.com/mymethod?name="tony",moreParamters=""... which will then insert the data into my database - so basically the URL would save whatever is passed to it?

Comment: The base url is the URL where your service is hosted, so yes, it can still work.